# Why list items need unique key, but other not, in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, unique

Why do rendering list items need to pass a key prop while other elements don't?

For example, if I do like -

```
['apple', 'orange', 'lemon'].map((fruit, i) => {
    return <li key={i}>{fruit}</li>;
});
```

The snippet before needs to pass the `key={i}` prop, But if I do the same job like-

```
<ul>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>lemon</li>
</ul>
```

In this case, we don't need to use the `key` prop.

**So, the question is why we need the key prop in the 1st case and why not in the 2nd case?**

Comment: in the second one, those elements are hard-coded and don't need updating at all, so the React system doesn't need to have any kind of hint from you about which elements need to update. That's really what the `key` is about -- on rerender, it's just saying `this item is supposed to be the same as that item from the previous render`

Comment: @TKoL your comment is satisfactory. Could you please elaborate on an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React official documentation talks about keys [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), among other places. Here's the key (no pun intended) quote:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

When you are rendering an array of elements, and that array may change, or the elements inside the array may change, supplying a `key` helps React to figure out which element in the array it should be updated. Not supplying a `key` can introduce bugs when React gets confused about which element it should be updating.

Your second example doesn't require a `key` because nothing is changing -- it's just a couple static elements, so there's no risk of React getting confused about what to update.

Answer (score 0):

The unique key warning that React gives you is just a warning, and it isn't always accurate. In your case, if the array of fruits never changes, then you actually don't need key even if React warns you.

React fallbacks to comparing down the line. Imagine this is your before/after:

Before

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

After

```
<ul>
  <li>new entry</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

React will default to matching down the line. It will match the previous `<li>A</li>` with `<li>new entry</li>`, etc. This would be bad if the elements had state. The solution is to use keys to match the elements up.

This is a common problem when people use arrays, so React provides us a sometimes-helpful warning.

Note that sometimes it won't warn you about keys but there'll still be a bug. For example, the following could be a bug if ListEle had state:

```
if(props.yesApple) {
    return (<ul>
        <ListEle>apple</ListEle>
        <ListEle>orange</ListEle>
        <ListEle>lemon</ListEle>
    </ul>);
}
else {
    return (<ul>
        <ListEle>orange</ListEle>
        <ListEle>lemon</ListEle>
    </ul>);
}
```

But React will not warn you.